# UIButton background color becomes white when running on iOS6

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I wonder why the buttons of my iPhone app is not displaying properly when running on an iOS 6 device.  I have set the buttons' background color to a blue color in Interface builder. However, when running on iOS 6 the buttons background became white.

This is how the button look like when running on iOS7

[image]

And this is how the buttons look like when running on iOS6

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[image]

Make your button `Custom` instead or `System` or `RoundRect`

Comment: Happy to hear that I could help you :]

Comment: @Pawan-Systematix Whats the difference between Custom, System and others. (Y)

Comment: @khunshan The main difference is look and feel. Different templates have different appearances. You can play with it and see them using `Interface Builder`.

Comment: so there is nothing but UI differences. ty @Pawan-Systematix

Comment: @khunshan you got it right the events a UIButton responds to are always same.

Comment: @jayantrawat Glad to hear that I could help you :)

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me

Comment: @MarceloGracietti Happy to hear that I could help you :)

Answer (score 5):

Change the button type to custom button in Interface builder.