# Swift- How to Display Image over Button?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to display an Image over a button, I'm getting BLUE PRINT of Image over button, I have tried so far this-

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var birdTexture1 = UIImage(named: "fish.png") as UIImage
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 10, 50, 150)
    button1.setImage(birdTexture1, forState: .Normal)

    button1.setTitle("Testing", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button1.addTarget(self, action: "btnAction:", forControlEvents:  UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button1)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

By above code, I m getting, the following output

[image]

But the Actual Image is this-

[image]

Comment: Change your button's type to `UIButtonTypeCustom`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325368/uibutton-background-color-becomes-white-when-running-on-ios6/21325546#21325546

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your UIButton needs to be of type UIButtonTypeCustom, rather than UIButtonTypeSystem.  You either constructed it as such, or need to update the UIButton's properties in interface builder.

More info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIButton/buttonWithType:

Answer (score 3):

i think replace this code:

```
let birdTexture1 = UIImage(named: "fish.png")! as UIImage
let button1:UIButton=UIButton(frame:CGRectMake(100, 50, 50, 150))
button1.setBackgroundImage(birdTexture1, forState: .Normal)
button1.setTitle("Testing", forState: .Normal)
button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.btnActionClick(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button1)

@IBAction func btnActionClick(sender:AnyObject){

}
```

and also add to image in target